# How to print custom characters

Tags: c, coding-style

I want to know how I can include special characters in C Strings, i.e.:

```
char a[] = "Hello \120"; // This is just an example
```

Then `a` should contain `"Hello <120th character>"`.

How can I do this in C?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you wrote? It should work as is. Just keep in mind that `'\120'` denotes 120 **octal**, i.e. 80 decimal.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I dont know that it was in octel. It is getting correctly

Comment: ...I forgot you could do it in octal too. My C got rusty once I started using Python for most things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In hex: `char a[] = "Hello \x78";`